# Configure Juniper SSL VPN on separate server for users

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

We have some client servers in USA and users in our LAN connect to these servers using Juniper SSL VPN client provided by the client.

Now the issue is, numbers of users are increasing and it's been very difficult for us to install Juniper VPN client on every user's PC. The solution which we are looking for is to configure separate Windows machine as a VPN which connects to Juniper SSL, and all users connect to this server and after that they would be able to connect to the client servers.

I am not sure if we can achieve this by using Windows routing and remote access.

If is it possible, then how ?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just trying to picture the infrastructure so you have servers in USA, workstations on a LAN wherever you are and Juniper SSL VPN on a workstation by workstation basis... So two sites one in USA (servers) one in wherever (workstations)... Where would you be looking to put this Windows RRAS machine then?

Comment: there are no sites.. we have some client servers in USA and manage these servers (RDC) from our office using juniper vpn. client imposed a user restriction on juniper vpn and its only limited to 5 users at the moment, but now more users want to connect these servers for troubleshooting purposes. the only solution which we are looking for to configure a separate server in our LAN which connects to juniper vpn and all users connect to client servers via this server. hope it clears

Comment: Right I understand now you want to configure an RDC server on your network to use as what is referred to as a 'jump server'. I think the problem your going to have is that the Juniper VPN Client is per user (logins) not per machine so you will still be limited to 5 connections. You could get round this by using some clever routing how is your knowledge on routes and network traffic?

Comment: yes. i tried to use RRAS with NAT but could not succeed.

Comment: Well you can kind of build a route map to the destination by using windows routing tables. For example I have one PC sitting with a LAN IP of 192.168.9.20 and a connection to Juniper VPN on IP 10.10.5.3 so my routing table says anything on 10.10.5.0/24 send to gateway 10.10.5.3 to find it.. Now if I have another PC who at the moment knows nothing about 10.10.5.0/24 I can add a route to say for 10.10.5.0/24 go to IP 192.168.9.20 because he knows where that location is.... does that make sense?